# Calling multiple functions on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, mouse

I have two functions that are called when the user clicks a button; first is that a timer will go off, the second one starts recording the distance the mouse has traveled. When the user clicks on a second button, the timer and recording stops, and the data are added to arrays. Though it would seem my code does not work when attempting to call the two different functions during the click event. Also, how do I reset the distance the mouse traveled in pixels back to zero again? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;
var timers = new Array();
var count = 0;
var mouseclickPositionList = new Array();
var mouseDistance = new Array();
var totalTravelled = 0;
var xTravelled = 0;
var yTravelled = 0;
var prevX, prevY, count = 0
var select = false;

function printMousePos(e) {
    var cursorX = e.clientX;
    var cursorY = e.clientY;
    prevY && (yTravelled += Math.abs(e.pageY - prevY));
    prevX && (xTravelled += Math.abs(e.pageX - prevX));

    prevX = e.pageX;
    prevY = e.pageY;

    totalTravelled = yTravelled + xTravelled;
    mouseDistance.push(totalTravelled);
    prevX, prevY, totalTravelled = 0;
}

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    printMousePos();
    doTimer();
} 

function timedCount() {
    t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
}

function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        timer_is_on = 1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on = 0;
    timers.push(t);
}
```

Comment: where is your html code ... would you please share that also

Comment: None of the functions are called in the button events in the html code

Comment: This seems like half the code; where is your HTML? Where is `mouseDistance` defined? Your `printMousePos` appears to do nothing...?

Comment: My apologies, i edited the code as above. printMousePos is supposed to record the distance traveled by the mouse when the user clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `printMousePos(e)` needs input data for processing of mouse position. So simply change listener registration to this form:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  //optionally put here code to stop bubbling the event
  printMousePos(e);
  doTimer();
}
```

If you have error in js file or script block the remaining code will not be processed. Your function  `printMousePos(e)` does so, because it operating with input attribute 'e' which is not provided. Just check out browser console for problem identification.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please elaborate what I should do?

Comment: Edit your code block that starts `document.addEventListener("click",` to what i post. Note the **e** letter, which represents click event.